# Ruby on Rails: How do I write a view to create a composite object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am modeling a `Bouquet` of `Flower` objects. I want to write a form which will allow me to create a `Bouquet`, create instances of `Flower` objects, and put them in the `Bouquet`.

I have modeled the following relationships.

1. `Bouquet` -- has_many --> `Flower`s.
2. `Flower` -- belongs_to --> `Bouquet`
3. Deleting a `Bouquet` will also delete the `Flower`s in it from the database.

Are there any patterns for creating a view which achieves the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with nested attributes. Your models will have a basic has_many/belongs_to association setup:

```
# app/models/bouquet.rb
class Bouquet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flowers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :flowers
end

# app/models/flower.rb
class Flower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bouquet
end
```

Note the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method, which allows you to save attributes on associated `Flower` records through the `Bouquet` parent.

In your strong params for the `BouquetsController`, you can whitelist the nested attributes for the bouquet's flowers, and built out some blank flowers to start with:

```
# app/controllers/bouquets_controller.rb
class BouquetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @bouquet = Bouquet.new
    5.times { @bouquet.flowers.build }
  end

  private

  def bouquet_params
    params.require(:bouquet).permit(:name, :size, flowers_attributes: [:color, :species])
  end
end
```

Now, in your form you can use `fields_for` to fill out information for your flowers within the bouquet:

```
<!-- app/views/bouquets/new.html.erb -->

<div class="create-form">
  <%= form_for @bouquet do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Bouquet Name" %>  
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label "Size of Bouquet" %>
    <%= f.text_field :size %>

    <%= fields_for :flower do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.label "Flower Name" %>
      <%= ff.text_field :name %>

      <%= ff.label "Species of Flower" %>
      <%= ff.text_field :species %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Passing a symbol of a relationship name to `fields_for` allows it to infer from that relationship how to render the nested fields within the form.

The above setup allows you to create a bouquet, and have its nested flowers automatically associated with it. Deleting a bouquet will remove all of its flowers as well. You can add some JS to make this form more dynamic (a button to add/remove individual flowers, for example).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Adding a variable number of flowers to the bouquet, I am guessing, will be more problematic? Will require some javascript tricks?